# Extra row after each row while serving a csv file in Django via s3

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I am trying to serve a csv file through a button click in Django. The file is stored on AWS s3 bucket. Below is my function in views.py:

```
def download(request):

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='my_bucket', Key='Output.csv')
    file = obj['Body']
    content = file
    response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Output.csv"'

    return response
```

When I click on the button, I can download the file easily. However, when I open the downloaded csv file in Microsoft Excel, there is an extra blank row after each row.

Is there a way to not get these extra lines in the downloadable file?

Comment: Looks like `\r\n` problem.
As fast workaround try: `HttpResponse(content.replace('\r', ''), ...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem was that the file which was getting stored in S3 was having alternate blank rows. So, there is no problem in the download function.